# Isotope executing before Images load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope, imagesloaded

I'm struggling to get my Isotope to execute after images load because otherwise, the Isotope items overlap. -  I am trying to apply the ImagesLoaded plugin (http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/) to my Isotope, however, I am struggling to execute the Isotope after Images load.

Below is my Isotope WITHOUT ImagesLoaded, if anyone knows how to go about this I'd be most grateful! (: Here is my Isotope in action: http://illuminategg.hol.es/portfolio.html

```
    var isotope_port = $('.port-isotope');
isotope_port.isotope({
    'itemSelector': '.item'
});

$('.port-filter a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');

    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    isotope_port.isotope({ filter: selector });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Did you get any error in the console?

Comment: I have since added a minimum height value to the images, seems to be working a lot better, not sure if 100% fixed though.

Answer (score 0):

For [imagesloaded](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout.html#imagesloaded), first add the script to your page since it is not part of isotope. Then use it as follows:

`var isotope_port = $('.port-isotope');
isotope_port.imagesLoaded( function() {
 isotope_port.isotope({
    'itemSelector': '.item'
});
});`